# Create new variable in sas, which is equal to the first digit of another variable

Tags: sas

I have a data set in SAS, which looks the following way:

1. Person disco
2. 1      3454
3. 2      3754
4. 3      4534
5. 4      4231
6. 5      5343

From the variable called `disco` I want to create a new variable, which is equal to the first digit of the `disco` variable:

1. Person disco  new_disco
2. 1      3454   3
3. 2      3754   3
4. 3      4534   4
5. 4      4231   4
6. 5      5343   5

I also want the `new_disco` variable to be a numeric variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the `substr()` and `input()` functions as follows:

```
data new;
set old;
new_disco=input(substr(disco,1,1),8.);
run;
```